# Jenkins - Pass tar file from Multijob to phase jobs

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to find the best way to get a tar file from a running MultiJob to the triggered phase jobs.

```
 - MultiJob starts
    - Phase 1 job needs to copy tar from MultiJob
    - Phase 2 job needs to copy tar from MultiJob
 - MultiJob does some other tasks
 - End of MultiJob
```

If I can archive as a build step, then I can copy it in the children processes, but unfortunately the only archiving I am finding is a post build action.

I have looked into trying to copy a file from one workspace to another, but this also seems to be a dead end.

Can anyone help me figure out the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your child jobs are using the same SCM source, you can use the [Shared Workspace plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Shared+workspace+plugin).

The plan is to define this shared workspace in the global Jenkins config, and next use this workspace in the relevant jobs.

Comment: The "phase 1" and "phase 2" jobs are shared between other multijobs (I call them function jobs as they work similar to functions). I am also not using the same slave for all the jobs. Shared Workspace doesn't seem to be working for me. However, if I didn't have such as strange setup, shared workspace would be exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: Another solution is to create network shared drive and to use this drive as a custom workspace for all your phase jobs.

Comment: That is a super good way to do it, but unfortunately my company won't allow me to do that. :( However, since this is the correct way to do it I am going to mark this as the correct answer.

Comment: Thanks @Kandyyoshia ;)

Answer (score 0):

The best way I could find to do this was to create a **sync** job in my first phase of the multijob. In that job it would tar all the files and archive the tar file.

Then each other phase job in the Multijob would pull the archive from the sync job using **build triggered by current Multijob build**

At the end, the Multijob would also pull the archive from the sync job and archive it, because I needed the archive in the Multijob  for a post promotion job that is triggered.

This method if far from a good one, but it will work for now. If anyone has better suggestions I am more than open to hearing them.